# Python turning 2 dimensional strings on my list into floats

Tags: python

I have a school project in which i need to make a 2 dimensional list and count the average point on that list. For some reason I can't change the values on the list into floats, even thought it prints them with print(pointslist[0][1]) into a single value.

```
def read_points():

print("Input the points, one per line as x,y.")
print("Stop by entering an empty line.")
arvo = 0
pointslist = []
while arvo != "":
    arvo = input("")
    kordinaatti = arvo.split(",")
    pointslist.append(kordinaatti)

return pointslist   

def calculate_midpoint(pointslist):

h = len(pointslist)
j = int(0)
summax = 0
summay = 0
while j <= h:
    arvox = pointslist[j][0]
    arvoy = pointslist[j][1]
    summax += float(arvox)
    summay += float(arvoy)
    summax = float(summax / h)
    summay = float(summay / h)
    j += 1       
return summax, summay
```

gives error:

```
summax += float(arvox)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ¨
```

The formatting is a bit off, but its correct on the code.

Thanks for that :) Now I see the problem, but i still have the problem with this part of the code:

```
def calculate_midpoint(pointslist):

h = len(pointslist)
j = 0
summax = 0
summay = 0
while j <= h:
    arvox = float(pointslist[j][0])
    arvoy = float(pointslist[j][1])
    summax += float(arvox)
    summay += float(arvoy)
    summax = float(summax / h)
    summay = float(summay / h)
    j += 1       
return summax, summay
```

goes out of index. The code works fine when I insert 0 for example instead of J. What value does J get, since it crashes the program?

The problem has been fixed, thanks to all of you who helped!!

Comment: What is the ¨ symbol doing in the above code? It looks like it's right after the function definition right now, which doesn't make syntactic sense.

Comment: arvoy = pointslist[j][0] should be arvoy = pointslist[j][1]. which causes another error claiming its out of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `read_points()` is returning a value that is a blank string that the `float` cannot do anything with.

If I do `read_points()` and enter `'5','4','3'` this is returned `[['5'], ['4'], ['3'], ['']]`  The last item in that list throws the error when `float('')` is attempted.  So either you need to fix it in `read_points()` to only return the inputted and not blank line, or deal with non-integers in the 2nd function.

So an alternate to your code could like:

```
def read_points():

    print("Input the points, one per line as x,y.")
    print("Stop by entering an empty line.")
    arvo = 0
    pointslist = []
    while arvo != "":
        arvo = input("")
        kordinaatti = arvo.split(",")
        pointslist.append(kordinaatti)

    return pointslist[:-1]   

def calculate_midpoint(pointslist):

    h = len(pointslist)-1
    j = int(0)
    summax = 0
    summay = 0
    while j <= h:
        arvox = pointslist[j][0]
        arvoy = pointslist[j][0]
        summax += float(arvox)
        summay += float(arvoy)
        summax = float(summax / h)
        summay = float(summay / h)
        j += 1       
    return summax, summay
```

Comment: Thanks, I used if instead of the return value, but now it claims J goes out of index in the func calculate_midpoint

Comment: Did you see the edit to calculate_midpoint?  The length of the pointslist will be too long since the index starts at 0.  so you need to subtract 1 or use `while j < h`

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding formatting issues, there are two bugs in your underlying code:

**Fencepost Issue in `read_points`**

`read_points` terminates after reading an empty line, but it *also* appends this empty line to `pointslist`, meaning that the last entry in `pointslist` is not valid. There are many ways to fix this: a simple one is to read at the end of each iteration rather than the start:

```
def read_points():
    print("Input the points, one per line as x,y.")
    print("Stop by entering an empty line.")
    arvo = 0
    pointslist = []
    arvo = input("")
    while arvo != "":
        kordinaatti = arvo.split(",")
        print(kordinaatti)
        pointslist.append(kordinaatti)
        arvo = input("")

    return pointslist
```

This is responsible for the "could not convert string to float" issue, since the last point is not a valid point.

**Off-by-one Issue in `calculate_midpoint`**

Your code iterates from `j=0` to `j=len(pointslist)`, and tries to access `pointslist[j]` at each iteration. This attempts to read `len(pointslist) + 1` items, which is incorrect; you should only read up to `j=len(pointslist) - 1`. This is responsible for the index error you mentioned in your comment on the OP.

Fixed version:

```
def calculate_midpoint(pointslist):
    print(pointslist)
    h = len(pointslist)
    j = int(0)
    summax = 0
    summay = 0
    while j < h:
        arvox = pointslist[j][0]
        arvoy = pointslist[j][0]
        summax += float(arvox)
        summay += float(arvoy)
        summax = float(summax / h)
        summay = float(summay / h)
        j += 1
    return summax, summay
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a good start but there are two mistakes in your code.

The first mistake was that the code that is reading the input is trying to treat the empty line as a float.

The second mistake was that the code that is calculating the mid-point is trying to process points beyond the end of the list by using `less than` or `equal to` in the comparison.

I have reworked your code to work correctly below.

```
def read_2d_points():
    '''
    Read 2D points from the command line.
    '''
    print("Input the points, one per line as x,y.")
    print("Stop by entering an empty line.")
    arvo = 0
    pointslist = []
    while arvo != "":
        arvo = input("? ")
        if ',' in arvo:
            # Ignore the case where the line is empty
            # to avoid a float conversion error.
            kordinaatti = [float(x.strip()) for x in arvo.split(",")]
            assert len(kordinaatti) == 2  # assume 2D
            pointslist.append(kordinaatti)
    assert len(pointslist) > 1
    return pointslist   


def calculate_midpoint(pointslist):
    '''
    Calculate the mid point.
    '''
    h = len(pointslist)
    j = int(0)
    summax = 0
    summay = 0
    while j < h:
        arvox = pointslist[j][0]
        arvoy = pointslist[j][1]
        summax += float(arvox)
        summay += float(arvoy)
        summax = float(summax / h)
        summay = float(summay / h)
        j += 1       
    return summax, summay

pointsList = read_2d_points()
print('points: {} {}'.format(len(pointsList), pointsList))
print('midpoint: {}'.format(calculate_midpoint(pointsList)))
```

If you are interested in expanding your python knowledge, i would suggest thinking about adding error handling (other than the assert), considering the use of either `classes` or `namedtuples` and, possibly, considering the use of list comprehensions.

Best of luck.